# OOP in PHP - object array iteration

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I am trying to iterate through array of objects in PHP, but I can't figure it out. This is my code:

```
    require_once("databaseConnect.php");
require_once("class/Ticket.php");

function showAll(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Ticket WHERE Status='1'";
    $p = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($p)){ 
        $t = new Ticket($row->IDTicket, $row->IDUser, $row->TotalOdd, $row->PlacedBet, $row->PossibleWin, $row->Status, $row->Won, $row->Time);
        $nizTiketa[] = $t;
    }
    return $nizTiketa;
}

$niz = showAll();

for ($i; $i<count($niz); $i++){
    echo $niz[$i]->getIDTicket()."<br/>";
}
```

and this is class Ticket:

```
class Ticket {
private $IDTicket;
private $IDUser;
private $TotalOdd;
private $PlacedBet;
private $PossibleWin;
private $Status;
private $Won;
private $Time;

function Ticket($idTicket, $idUser, $totalOdd, $placedBet, $possibleWin, $status, $won, $time) {
    $this->IDTicket = $idTicket;
    $this->IDUser = $idUser;
    $this->TotalOdd = $totalOdd;
    $this->PlacedBet = $placedBet;
    $this->PossibleWin = $possibleWin;
    $this->Status = $status;
    $this->Won = $won;
    $this->Time = $time;
}

function getIDTicket(){
    return $this->IDTicket;
}

function setIDTicket($idTicket){
    $this->IDTicket = $idTicket;
}
```

.
.
.

I got error  Call to a member function getIDTicket() on a non-object

How should it be done?

Comment: Just for sanity, add in `$nizTiketa = array();` at the top of `function showAll()` - always initialise your array before adding something into it :)

Comment: Are you sure that you must initialize array in php?

Comment: The thing is that the variable `$nizTiketa` will not exist if no rows matched the query. That's strictly speaking an error you'll want to avoid by initializing the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things I'd do here for sanity...

1. As mentioned by Joe, initialise your array before adding elements, eg

   ```
   function showAll() {
       $nizTiketa = array();
       // ...
   ```
2. Either initialise your iteration counter `$i` to zero

   ```
   for ($i = 0, $count = count($niz); $i < $count; $i++)
   ```

   or more simply, use `foreach`

   ```
   foreach ($niz as $ticket) {
       echo $ticket->getIDTicket(), "<br/>";
   }
   ```